# Splash screen getting invoked on map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios5, mapkit

I am working on a small project and my query is i have a view which displays the map and prompts me to use my current location.

my query is that when i press allow or dont allow button of the pop up it relaunches my app displaying my splash screen and then takes me back to my mapview.

So can we stop this from happening and does anyone know why this happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: am just adding the show user location property to yes thats all that i am doing

Comment: You have written no code, just checked the user location property? I can't see why you app restarts, also apps crash they will never restart. Is there any out but in de bug console. You will have to give us more information or we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, this "question" is hard to answer. Here's a try:

The popup is actually not shown by your app, but by iOS. Upon return of the popup, your application delegate's `-applicationDidBecomeActive` will get called. Apparently you (or the person who wrote the code for you) takes this as a sign to launch your splash screen. Of course, this should only happen when coming from the background or on startup.

So my guess is that the app is actually not relaunched at all. Put some logging in each of the application delegate functions, to see when and in what order they are called.